# React Hooks Updating Array State Causes Infinite Loop

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am updating my `nudgeList` state within an `if` condition. If the condition is `true`, I insert a number of objects into my empty state array

```
  const [avgOrderCount, setAvgOrderCount] = useState('')
  const [productCategory, setProductCategory] = useState('')
  const [ecoPackage, setEcoPackage] = useState('')
  const [domesticDelivery, setDomesticDelivery] = useState('')
  const [foreignSalesTypeList, setforeignSalesTypeList] = useState([]
  const [nudgeList, setNudgeList] = useState([]) 

  if (Number(avgOrderCount) <= 9999) {
    if ((productCategory === ProductCategoryType.BEAUTY || productCategory === ProductCategoryType.SOME_BEAUTY) && ecoPackage === ecoPackageType.YES && domesticDelivery === domesticDeliveryType.YES && !foreignSalesTypeList.includes('open_market') && !foreignSalesTypeList.includes('export') && !foreignSalesTypeList.includes('none') && foreignSalesTypeList.length >= 1) {
      setNudgeList(list => [...list, eco, sample, orderSheet, wrongDelivery, oliveYoung, api, fifo, manager])
    }
  }
```

However, after I test my code I get the error

```
Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.
```

I suspect the problem lies with how I am updating my state

```
setNudgeList(list => [...list, eco, sample, orderSheet, wrongDelivery, oliveYoung, api, fifo, manager])
```

But I am confused why this is triggering an infinite loop when I just have one `if` condition.

How do I resolve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `useEffect` fixes the problem

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (Number(avgOrderCount) <= 9999) {
      if ((productCategory === ProductCategoryType.BEAUTY || productCategory === ProductCategoryType.SOME_BEAUTY) && ecoPackage === ecoPackageType.YES && domesticDelivery === domesticDeliveryType.YES && !foreignSalesTypeList.includes('open_market') && !foreignSalesTypeList.includes('export') && !foreignSalesTypeList.includes('none') && foreignSalesTypeList.length >= 1) {
        console.log('it works')
        setNudgeList(list => [...list, eco, sample, fedex, orderSheet, wrongDelivery, oliveYoung, api, fifo, manager])
      }
    }
  }, [avgOrderCount, productCategory, ecoPackage, domesticDelivery, foreignSalesTypeList])
```

Answer (score 1):

setNudgeList will re-render your component.
But your `if condition Number(avgOrderCount) <= 9999` will always `true`
So, setNudgeList will be called every render.

Comment: I see so it works like a while loop always stuck on `true`?

Answer (score 1):

if your condition is true, you will trigger a Re-render of the component by setting the NudgeList. In the Re-render, if your condition is still true, setting NudgeList will trigger the next Re-render, hence the infinite loop. you should use effect to handle the setting function. For example:

```
useEffect(()=>{
  if (Number(avgOrderCount) <= 9999) {
    if ((productCategory === ProductCategoryType.BEAUTY 
  || productCategory === ProductCategoryType.SOME_BEAUTY) 
  && ecoPackage === ecoPackageType.YES 
  && domesticDelivery === domesticDeliveryType.YES 
  && !foreignSalesTypeList.includes('open_market') 
  && !foreignSalesTypeList.includes('export') 
  && !foreignSalesTypeList.includes('none') 
  && foreignSalesTypeList.length >= 1) {
      setNudgeList(list => [...list, eco, sample, orderSheet, wrongDelivery, oliveYoung, api, fifo, manager])
    }
  }

}, [avgOrderCount, productCategory...//all the dependence, sorry they are too many ])
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that there's nothing in either of your conditions that prevents the `setNudgeList` call from being run again (or a check that it has already run). So each time your component renders, it runs the `setNudgeList` call, which triggers a re-render, which again invokes `setNudgeList`.

You can fix this by wrapping this logic within a `useEffect` hook and setting the dependency array accordingly. As long as you either omit `nudgeList` from the dependency array or include a check on the value of `nudgeList` within the `useEffect` call you should avoid infinite re-renders.

The [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook only calls the given callback when the value of anything in the dependency array changes. This way you can control which changes should cause the effect to run again.

Example:

```js
  const [avgOrderCount, setAvgOrderCount] = useState('')
  const [productCategory, setProductCategory] = useState('')
  const [ecoPackage, setEcoPackage] = useState('')
  const [domesticDelivery, setDomesticDelivery] = useState('')
  const [foreignSalesTypeList, setforeignSalesTypeList] = useState([]
  const [nudgeList, setNudgeList] = useState([]) 


  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (Number(avgOrderCount) <= 9999) {
      if ((productCategory === ProductCategoryType.BEAUTY || productCategory === ProductCategoryType.SOME_BEAUTY) && ecoPackage === ecoPackageType.YES && domesticDelivery === domesticDeliveryType.YES && !foreignSalesTypeList.includes('open_market') && !foreignSalesTypeList.includes('export') && !foreignSalesTypeList.includes('none') && foreignSalesTypeList.length >= 1) {
        setNudgeList(list => [...list, eco, sample, orderSheet, wrongDelivery, oliveYoung, api, fifo, manager])
      }
    }
  }, [avgOrderCount, productCategory, ecoPackage, domesticDelivery, foreignSalesTypeList]);
```

Note this will still cause `nudgeList` to be updated if any of the values in the dependency array (`avgOrderCount`, `productCategory`, `ecoPackage`, `domesticDelivery`, or `foreignSalesTypeList`) changes. So you may also want to add a check on the value of `nudgeList` or another variable to keep track of whether you've already updated `nudgeList` or not.